# need help for the pandas dataset to get the count values based on 2 different columns

Tags: python, pandas

i had an IPL dataset how can i get the details who are the most title winners, i am able to get the details by using the below commands, is thier any other way to do it, using single line of code.

x=final_df.query('Stage=="Final"') --> it will get all the match details which are the Final and created a new data frame
x['Winner'].value_counts() --> now i am querying the x data frame
Winner
Mumbai Indians           5
Chennai Super Kings      5
Kolkata Knight Riders    2
Gujarat Titans           1
Rajasthan Royals         1
Deccan Chargers          1
Sunrisers Hyderabad      1
Name: count, dtype: int64

is thier any other ways to get the below output

Winner
Mumbai Indians           5
Chennai Super Kings      5
Kolkata Knight Riders    2
Gujarat Titans           1
Rajasthan Royals         1
Deccan Chargers          1
Sunrisers Hyderabad      1

Comment: Is the question how to do this in one line? If so:
`final_df.query('Stage=="Final"')["Winner"].value_counts()` will give the equivalent result.
Or is the question, how to do it in a fundamentally different way?

Comment: both how to do it in one line and fundamentally different way to do